# Sessão de Login em uma Aplicação

Tags: php, session, login, php-5

Boa Tarde Galera, estou fazendo um sistema para empresa onde trabalho porém estou com um problema que eu nao consigo resolver.

Este é o Código que estou utilizando:

## Código para mostrar usuário e cargo

```
require('conBanco.php'); #conexão com o Banco de Dados
if(isset($_POST['UsrEmail']) && isset($_POST['UsrSenha'])){ #Caso o usuário esteja logando
    $queryUser1 =  mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE UsrEmail = '$_POST[UsrEmail]' AND UsrSenha = '$_POST[UsrSenha]' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($queryUser1) != 0){
        if($queryUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryUser1)){
            $_SESSION['UserLogado'] = $queryUser['UsrID']; #Salva em uma variável de Sessão a ID do usuário que está logado
            header('Location: login.php');
        }else{
            echo $LoginErro;
            
        }
    }else{
        echo $LoginErro;
    }
}else{ #Caso o usuário já esteja logado
    $QueryLogado = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT UsrID, UsrNome, UsrSenha, UsrEmail, UsrNvl, NvlNome FROM usuarios INNER JOIN usuarionivel ON UsrNvl = NvlID;"));
    echo "Bem vindo <b>".$QueryLogado['UsrNome']."</b>, tudo bem?<br>Não esqueça que você é <b>".$QueryLogado['NvlNome']."</b> nesta Empresa!";
    echo '<br><a href=../config/Deslogar.php>Sair</a>';
}
```

O Problema é o seguinte:
Eu quero mostrar ao usuário o nome dele e o cargo dele na empresa porém, sempre que eu faço login com qualquer usuário diferente, com e-mails diferentes ele só mostra o nome do ADMINISTRADOR.

alguém sabe onde posso estar errando ?

Comment: Um comentário: você, em algum momento, está inicializando a sessão com o método session_start()? Para armazenar os dados na global $_SESSION, você deve fazer isso antes. Pergunto isso pois quando o usuário está logado, qual parâmetro você utiliza para  recuperar ele? Aparentemente nenhum. Deve retornar sempre o mesmo: o administrador.

Comment: Não Consegui Entender muito bem a parte de qual parametro estou usando, e sim estou iniciando a sessão na pagina e capturando os dados no codigo acima na variavel $queryuser.

Comment: Na situação onde o usuário já está logado, abaixo do comentário: "#Caso o usuário já esteja logado", você não passa nenhum parâmetro para query que indica qual usuário deve ser retornado, sendo assim, o retornado deve ser sempre o "Administrador". Adicione um parâmetro na consulta para retornar o usuário de acordo com a sessão.

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite pelo oq eu entendi cara o erro deve ser no banco de dados. 
pega a query montada com email diferente que vc  está testando e testa direto no banco de dados para ver se está retornando certo.

porque vc falou que o erro só persiste quando se loga com outro usuario.

Comment: Sua resposta não resolve o problema. Seria melhor convertido em comentado na pergunta...

Comment: Desculpa ai mais não me lembro de ter pedido sua opinião para algo?

Comment: Boa tarde Colega, no banco ele faz exatamente a mesma coisa, eu preciso saber exatamente onde estou errando, provavelmente é no codigo mesmo.